# Are there any efficient algorithms for finding shortest cycle length?

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, cycle

Given problem : For given a undirected graph, find the shortest cycle of the length.

I found the O(E(ElogV)) [algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-minimum-weight-cycle-undirected-graph/), but it still so slow for solving the problem.

Are there any efficient algorithm for this problem?

Comment: If the edges are unweighted, then the length of this cycle is called the *girth* of the graph.  Hopefully this will be useful for further googling :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best known algorithm (due to Itai and Rodeh) for computing the length of a shortest cycle of an *n*-vertex graph takes time *O*(*M*(*n*) log *n*), where *M*(*n*) is the time required for multiplying two *n*-by-*n* matrices.

A. Itai and M. Rodeh. Finding a minimum circuit in a graph. *SIAM Journal on Computing*,7(4):413–423, 1978.